# How to use file parameter in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am executing parameterised build in jenkins to count no. of lines in file which has 1 file parameter. Its file location is `pqr`. The name of the script file is `linecount.sh` which is saved at remote server. When i tried to execute it using command `sh linecount.sh` filename, it works perfectly from jenkins. But as i remove filename from the argument and execute same script as parameterised build it is showing below error on console :

```
Started by user Prasoon Gupta
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace users/Prasoon/sample_programs
Copying file to pqr
[sample_programs] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3529902665956638862.sh
+ sh linecount.sh
PRASOON4
linecount.sh: line 15: parameterBuild.txt: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am uploading file (`parameterBuild.txt`) from my local machine. Why is it giving this error?

My doubt is in shell script I used argument as `$1`. How can I refer this when I am taking file as parameter.

Comment: Make sure that the parameter file is inserted as you expect into the workspace, e.g. do a `ls -l` in your shell command.

Comment: Thank you but i want to upload it directly from my local machine, want to make my job more user friendly.

Comment: Yes, understand that. But in order to isolate the issue, what happens if you run `ls -l` as part of your shell command in the job configuration? E.g. does it list `parameterBuild.txt` there or any other files?

Comment: No, it doesn't lists parameterBuild.txt there but a new file named same as logical name of my file location (here pqr) is created there having all the content as in parameterBuild.txt.

Comment: Ah, I see, my bad, misread some of your question. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 36):

The uploaded file will not retain the same name as it has on your local computer. It will be named after the `File location` argument specified in the file parameter settings:
[image]
In this example I will get a file called `file.txt` in my workspace root, regardless of what I call it on my computer.
So if I now build my job and enter the following in the parameter dialog (note that my local filename is table.html):

[image]

Then I get the following in the log (I have a build step which does `ls -l`):

```
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/fs
Copying file to file.txt
[fs] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson845437350739055843.sh
+ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 292 Feb 15 07:23 file.txt
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Note that `table.html` now is called `file.txt`, e.g. what I entered as `File location`.

So in you're case the command should be:

```
sh linecount.sh pqr
```

Comment: @JonS Thanks for the clarification. Additionaly from a Job A, I wanted to trigger Job B in a Remote Server. Job B is parameterized and takes file as an input. I use Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin. If I pass the file in Load parameters from external file field of Job A, its not getting read properly in the Job B. Any suggestions ??

Comment: @Santhosh Sorry, I have no idea, I suggest that you post a separate question

Comment: can this file parameter filed be made mandatory.So that, without uploading the file, the build should fail.

Comment: @vishal, probably a separate question, but, just a shot in the dark, I think you simply could check if the file exists, and if not fail the script

Comment: i have exactly that flow - parent project passes file with parameters, child project has input file parameter with the `File location` as scan.txt (it is property file with lines key=value) , there is a build step  - powershell with ```#read input file
$props = convertfrom-stringdata (get-content ./scan.txt -raw)
write-host "params1: xx=$($props.xx) yy=$($props.yy)"``` and it prints values properly.  as indicated above it worth to check workspace of you child project if it has that file parameter; in your case - `file.txt` should be present

Answer (score 2):

There is a a bug since ages that makes impossible to use `fileParameter`:

- [Handle file parameters](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27413)
- [file parameter not working in pipeline job](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47333)

Comment: Note there's a solution in the comments after you configure the needed plugin & signatures. Something along the lines `def inputFile = input message: 'Upload file', parameters: [file(name: 'data.zip')]
            unzip dir: '', glob: '', zipFile: inputFile.remote`

Comment: The comments on your first link say in Feb 2021 a plugin was released for this functionality: https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround for this issue https://github.com/janvrany/jenkinsci-unstashParam-library
and in a pipeline script you do:

```
library "jenkinsci-unstashParam-library"
node {
  def file_in_workspace = unstashParam "file"
  sh "cat ${file_in_workspace}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's to do with Free-Style job & if your configuration looks similar to this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH7mQ.png then you can run simply do `sh linecount.sh ${pqr}` to get what you are looking for?