# How to input json file as input parameter to jenkins job?

Tags: java, jenkins

How to input json file as input parameter to **jenkins** job?

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to use Jenkins Pipeline, you can refer the following code:

```
node {
    deleteDir()
    stage("upload") {
         def inputFile = input message: 'Upload file', parameters: [file(name: 'input.json')]
         new hudson.FilePath(new File("$workspace/input.json")).copyFrom(inputFile)
    inputFile.delete()
    }
   stage("checkout") {
         echo fileExists('input.json').toString()
         def props = readJSON file: '$workspace/input.json' // Read the json file
    }
    }
```

Some Links to refer:

- [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080876/jenkins-pipeline-job-with-file-parameter)
- [Reading a json file](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readjson-code-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace)
- If you dont want to use a Jenkins pipeline job refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224691/how-to-use-file-parameter-in-jenkins) link