# Jenkins- How to use File Parameter in Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

If I use File parameter in declarative way, it gives the exception below.

But the same command works fine in freestyle job.

Is there any way to upload file of any format (xls, properties) into Jenkins workspace using declarative way, if not File parameter?

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at hudson.model.FileParameterValue.doDynamic(FileParameterValue.java:205)
>   at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.dispatch(MetaClass.java:397)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)
>   Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException

Comment: Please include the pipeline file that is causing this error and if needed review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: pipeline { 
    agent any 
    parameters {
  file description: 'some desc', name: 'abc.text'
}

    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps { 
                echo "error the file is not copied in workspace"
            }
        }
    }
}
most basic pipeline - which accepts file parameter from Jenkins UI.
thanks @Stefan Crain for respondng so quick.

Comment: I believe its similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49833240/how-to-input-json-file-as-input-parameter-to-jenkins-job/49835306#49835306