# Wget command not executed through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, command-line

So my problem is very weird, tried searching all around but not able to find the solution. My goal was to download something using wget using a Jenkins job. I confirmed wget works through command line, also placed wget in system32 folder, as to be invoked from anywhere. I put below command in a bat file and when I try to execute the bat file, like "E:\utilitydownload.bat" in Jenkins using Execute windows batch command, it returns **'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Content of utilitydownload.bat

```
E:
cd E:\wgetdownload
wget <some file on a server>
```

Comment: Provide the full-path to the `wget` executable in your script.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\wget.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please [don't cross-post](https://superuser.com/q/1556088/497981)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little weird but i'm not sure why it didn't work from `C:\Windows\System32`. I also tried adding `Path` environment variable in Slave Configure section but to no avail.

However, if i keep the executable anywhere else, for example, `C:\softwares\wget.exe`, it works.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Also could you suggest how should I parameterize <some file on a server> ?

Comment: That's a separate question. See if this plugin fulfills your purpose: https://plugins.jenkins.io/filesystem-list-parameter-plugin/ OR if this link helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224691/how-to-use-file-parameter-in-jenkins