# trigger jenkins job with file paramter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a python script. I need to trigger jenkins job remotely using file parameter. That means I have a file and that file needs to be uploaded to remote Jenkins pipeline job. Please let me know if it will work or not ? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a string parameter with your file's path.
in addition, you can use "file parameter" as described in Jenkins documentation: [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-parameters/), and referenced in the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42224691/how-to-use-file-parameter-in-jenkins)